# How To Make Div Contents Become Obscured As Div Shrinks

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

If this is a duplicate, as seems likely, I can't find it asked anywhere else on here - I have looked!

I have a `div` which appears and disappears using `$(#myDiv).animate({width:'toggle'},1000)`. It works great, but the problem is that, as the `div` expands and contracts, the contents resize dynamically, as one would expect, since I'm just changing its width. But what I want is for the contents of the `div` not to resize, so that as the `div` expands the contents are slowly revealed, and as it shrinks again the contents are hidden.

I've created a fiddle [here](http://www.bootply.com/wlwR0Szyye) to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
  <div id="wrapper" style="overflow:hidden">
  <div id="content" style="width: 300px">
```

Here's your modified fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/Tj6NndCDJY

Note that setting the width of the internal div is essential, otherwise the internal div will inherit the width from its shrinking parent.

Comment: Works perfectly in the fiddle, thank you. I think I tried something very similar to this, without success, and trying to implement it in my project isn't working, but at least now I know that it SHOULD work and the problem obviously lies elsewhere.